# Apache RewriteRule executing twice

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a quite simple need : to redirect any request to a single file.

So I put, at my apache directory root, a .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ index.php?q=test [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

All the requests are indeed redirected to *index.php* but a wierd thing appears : the PHP *$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']* contains *q=test&q=test* showing that the redirection occurs twice (and the REDIRECT_URL doesn't contains *index.php* but the passed URL leading to it being equal to REQUEST_URI.

How can I fix that, considering that I have only .htaccess way to configure Apache ?

Testing :

- Create a folder at your apache web root (ex: redirect/)
- add a .htaccess file containing the code above
- add a index.php file dumping $_SERVER to see the result
- try any URL (ex: redirect/foo/bar) and you should see the dump.

Apache version : 2.4.33 ; PHP version : 7.2.4 (& 5.6.35) ; WAMP (Win) & Red Hat (Linux).

Comment: Using [QSA] flag will combine the query strings

Comment: Sure but as you can see its will combine them twice. QSA is used on purpose so the query passed by the user is saved but an additionnal parameter is set (here: q=test).

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem and couldn't.  Created a simple directory with your .htaccess and dumped $_SERVER and only see the query string in there once, even if I start with the index.php?q=test as the origin (which I thought was the problem, it would then take that and put it on there again), but it didn't happen.  Running 2.4.29 on Ubuntu. Maybe there is something causing the second redirection?

Comment: @Katie well it seems the copy/paste of my .htaccess failed and removed the space before [L,QSA] ; my bad here, edited my OP.

Comment: Yes, I had fixed that in my test case, figured it just didn't translate over to the post :) If you want to add what URLs you were sending in and the results, I can try to match it in my test

Comment: Any URL should show the problem except index.php : added an exemple in my OP.